# Coldfusion Bug, CFFILE worked on my dev box with CF7, stopped working on Prod with CF9

Tags: coldfusion

Here's a coldfusion bug that I can't figure out where to even start debuging....

On DEV, I have CF7, and use CFFILE to upload, and rename a file... Uploaded Images etc...

Now I deployed on Prod with CF9 and all image uploads don't work and are not erroring. Any ideas what could be wrong? Permission? Is there even a way to debug this bec CF isn't spitting out errors.

Thanks!

B

Comment: Not an answer, but differences between your development environment and your production environment are a liability to you, particularly when its something as significant as the pre-processing server being two versions out of date. When you're building on CF7 and deploying on CF9, it's not a question of "if" a problem like this will occur, but "when".

Comment: Have you checked the CF logs, specifically application.log?

Comment: I have checked the log and nothing is showing up there.... Not sure if this is relevant but it's a windows box, hosted on EC2, and the file is supposed to be written to an EC2 drive. thxs

Comment: ok I think I might know what it is. IN CF7 I was using IMAGECFC which apparently doesn't play nicely cin CF9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I see issues with files not being written properly it's almost always a permissions issue. Specifically, that the account the ColdFusion (or JRUN.EXE) service is running under does not have permission to write to the desired resource.

Don't run CF under the SYSTEM account. Create a special user account that has the permissions needed and run CF under that. *(Don't run CF under an Administrator account, either.)*

Comment: How do I figure out which account has CF or JRUN running under?

Comment: Need to look in Task Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Do you have try/catch around the upload?
- Is there any errors in the server logs?
- Where are you uploading to?
- Can you create a very simple test page and get cffiles to work?

Comment: Also check what path `GetTempDirectory()` returns and if the CF service has write permission there.

Comment: Tomalak, how do I see if it has write permission? CFFILE upload something?

Comment: @Jason, for some strange reason the TRY/CATCH isn't picking anything up. And the files aren't getting to the set directory in CFUPLOAD

Comment: if you are using variables for any of the attributes in your cffile tag then I would output those variables and make sure they are what you expect. Also, try to hard code the correct values and see if that works.